# Компилятор останавливается на пробеле

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
    int m=0;
    char s[100];
    cin>>s;
    for ( int i=0; i < strlen(s)-2; i++) {
        if((s[i]=='a')&&(s[i+1]=='b')&&(s[i+2]=='c'))
            m++;
    }
    cout<<m<<endl;
}
```

Comment: это как? откуда такая информация?)))

Comment: какая информация?)

Comment: Вы не путаете компилятор с вашей программой?

Comment: ну может и путаю)) просто это связано с моей учебой, у меня не очень получается писать программы, вот и обратился сюда за помощью

Answer (score 1):

код видимо  написан под какой то очень старый компилятор. Как минимум его нужно переписать так

```
#include<iostream> // с .h нет такого файла
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdio>

int main() { // void тип не принято писать.
  int m=0;
  std::string s;
  std::getline(std::cin,s); // здесь может быть и std::cin >> s; но тогда будет только до первого пробела.
  for ( size_t i=0; i < s.length() - 2 ; i++) { // здесь нужен - 2, что бы не выйти за пределы.
    if((s[i]=='a')&&(s[i+1]=='b')&&(s[i+2]=='c')) // здесь можно  было бы и красивее написать, но я уже так оставил
      m++;
  }
  std::cout << m << std::endl;
  return 0; // очень желательно в конец добавить
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое)) я пишу на visual studio 6.00)) а нельза его на этом языке программирования написать? был бы очень благодарен

Comment: 6.00 - это среда программирования. Но плюсы там конечно особенные, но не настолько. Переделанный код должен компилироваться.

Comment: MS VC 6.0 -- это конец 90х. Практически сразу после приёма стандарта на C++, т.е. суровая архаика. Из встречающихся, хотя и крайне редко -- только BC 3.1, который вообще "страуструп-1"